# Getting error whenever I try updating powerpoint chart in Python using pptx library

Tags: python, charts, python-pptx

I've been using this code to try to add a value into my new chart. I'm a bit confused with the documentation as I am still new to Python. Basically going off from the example on the website I have the categories East, West and Midwest with values 19.2,21.4,16.7. I want to add the category North with the value 40. When I run this code I get the error: Powerpoint found a problem with content...
How can I fix this code so it updates the new data?

Code:

```
chart = prs.slides[5].shapes[1].chart #chart identified on slide 
chart_data = CategoryChartData()
chart_data.categories = ["East","West","Midwest","North"]
chart_data.add_series = ("Series 1", (19.2,21.4,16.7,40))
chart.replace_data(chart_data)
prs.save('Template_Test_2.pptx')
```

I'm trying to run excel into it but I just want to get the basics established before I do that.
Here's a photo of the chart I have:
[image]

Comment: Could you provide the full traceback (error sequence) that you're getting? When I ran the example from the `pptx` documentation, but added in the 'North' value that you're suggesting, it executed without error and produced a PowerPoint file as expected. But you have `chart.replace_data(chart_data)` which is not in the documentation example. Is that line the source of the error?

Comment: Hey, I provided the solution below. Turns out that I inserted an equal signs after the .addseries part which is why it was giving me that error

Answer (score 1):

Error is due to invalid syntax. Instead should be

```
chart_data.add_series("Series 1", (19.2,21.4,16.7,40))
```